# Deprecation behavior using the [Obsolete] attribute

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

While removing some obsolete code I came across an unexpected scenario, recreated below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ViableMethod();
        Console.WriteLine("");    
        SoftDeprecatedMethod();//Compiler warning

        //HardDeprecatedMethod();//Can't call that from here, compiler error

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    public static void ViableMethod ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ViableMethod, calls SoftDeprecatedMethod");
        SoftDeprecatedMethod();//Compiler warning
        //HardDeprecatedMethod();//Can't call that from here, compiler error
    }

    [Obsolete("soft", false)]
    public static void SoftDeprecatedMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SoftDeprecatedMethod, calls HardDeprecatedMethod");
        HardDeprecatedMethod();
    }

    [Obsolete("hard", true)]
    public static void HardDeprecatedMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HardDeprecatedMethod");
    }
}
```

Based in the output it seems that functions deprecated with a warning are permitted to call functions deprecated with an error and the code will execute.

My expectation was that I would see a compiler error complaining that the call to `HardDeprecatedMethod()` from `SoftDeprecatedMethod()` is not permitted.
The observed behavior seems odd to me.

Does anyone know if this is the desired behavior (and if so, why), or could this be a flaw in the implementation of the `[Obsolete]` attribute?

Comment: Great question. I suspect it's deliberate (as it can sometimes make the deprecation process a lot smoother), but it's *not* covered in the language specification.

Comment: @JonSkeet When I read the question my first thought was "gosh, why hasn't Jon answered that one?" and then I read your comment. That was kind of...unexpected :-)

Comment: Just another note, `[Obsolete]` is an [Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx), not a keyword. You are more than welcome to name a variable/class 'Obsolete' if you so choose.

Comment: @Krumelur: Yes, I was really hoping it would be an easily-answered question, just quoting the spec. Then it turned out not to be...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In facts it's the other way around: It shows that C# compiler is smart and very clear on the use of methods marked with `Obsolete`.

Assume that you are providing this code as a public API in a class library to Bob.

1. You expect if Bob calls `HardDeprecatedMethod` in his code, he should get a compile time error; and he will.
2. You expect if Bob has called `SoftDeprecatedMethod` anywhere, from this time forward, he should be warned about that, BUT his code should still work; and it will.

So you get what exactly you want!